# Restart a meteor js application process (forever process) on server reboot

Tags: meteor, forever

I'm currently working on an application developed with meteor.js framework and database as nosql (mongodb). The application is hosted on a Linux server. We currently have an issue wherein on unexpected server reboots (application server) the application process (forever.js) doesn't starts up automatically.

We are planning to schedule the script, which we use to start the process manually, on server reboot through crontab. Also we want to implement a periodic health check on application (which will check for applications availability) in the script.

Below is a small part of the script which is responsible to start the application process.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1YZ4.png)

Please advice if there can be any other better approach to achieve this scenario.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This answer may help you

[Running Meteor Application on a Single Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308179/running-meteor-application-on-a-single-core/41308722#41308722)

It's not exactly the same, but will give you some options

1. Phusion Passenger
2. Forever
3. MUP
4. Galaxy

Answer (score 0):

I think this is overcomplicated...

With Meteor you deploy a production bundle for your specific server and that is all you need to do. You don't need to use forever or any other scripts. Please check this project in case you are not familiar with MUP: http://meteor-up.com/